# API for searching Orphan Drug Designations and Approvals

Tags: api, data.gov, openfda, healthcare-finder-api, drugs

I'm building a website using the openFDA APIs, which works perfectly.

I also notice that the FDA website provides a tool called "Search Orphan Drug Designations and Approvals" at https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/opdlisting/oopd/index.cfm

I wonder if there is any API for this search tool.

If not, is there any way I can incorporate this search tool into my website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

chaohuang -- OpenFDA does not have an API for this dataset. And I can't find an API for it elsewhere either unfortunately. As a possible alternative approach, you may be able to implement a solution based on downloading the list as an Excel file. The tool supports Excel file downloads (Chose "Download Excel file" from the Output Format field), and (according the website) the list of drugs gets updated monthly.